# how to use @Relation in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

```
{
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Reading monthly hot list in January",
        "img_url": "http://image.wufazhuce.com/FteWZbumJ0vugA_oF-tjk9OxOhT5",
        "contents": [
            {
                "id": "4582",
                "title": "How to say goodbye",
                "subtitle": "Gengsheng Su",
                "category": 1,
                "cover": "http://image.wufazhuce.com/FnBm-nZ-fQIit227taKI9Tue_9sx?imageView2/1/w/120/h/120",
                "maketime": "2021-01-20 06:00:00",
                "weight": 15
            },
            {
                "id": "4567",
                "title": "Go to RT Mart",
                "subtitle": "Zhanhei Wang",
                "category": 1,
                "cover": "http://image.wufazhuce.com/Fv2ZTzdL0LjfzB8q5N_mp_7h5Ti8?imageView2/1/w/120/h/120",
                "maketime": "2021-01-09 06:00:00",
                "weight": 14
            },
            {
                "id": "4560",
                "title": "cLOUD MADE BY RAIN",
                "subtitle": "GongChen",
                "category": 1,
                "cover": "http://image.wufazhuce.com/FnZhpbcENaSm6Fmnjfxaz0oAgXzo?imageView2/1/w/120/h/120",
                "maketime": "2021-01-01 06:00:00",
                "weight": 13
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to use this json convert to **bean**,and store it in my **Room**.
But I don't know how to store it.Maybe I'm not familiar with **Room**.

I tried to use it by

```
@Entity(tableName = "rebang_cache")
data class ReBang(
        @PrimaryKey
        var id: Int,
        var title: String?,
        var img_url: String?,
        @Relation(
                parentColumn = "id",
                entityColumn = "id")
        val contents: List<ContentBean>?) {

    @Entity
    data class ContentBean(@PrimaryKey
                           var id: String,
                           var title: String?,
                           var subtitle: String?,
                           var category: Int?,
                           var cover: String?,
                           var maketime: String?,
                           var weight: Int?)
}
```

But it is error.I want to know how to implement it.

I think this is a good question!

Comment: Hi @pnkj can share the error message

Comment: oh，I don't think the error message is important because it's my usage error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define entity classes for both parent and child first:

```
@Entity(tableName = "rebang_cache")
data class ReBang( 
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long,
    val title: String
    //...)

@Entity
data class ContentBean(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    //parent model reference id
    val rebangId: Long,
    val title: String,
    //..)
```

Then define one-to-many relationship using `@Relation` annotation

```
data class ReBangWithContents(
    @Embedded val rehang: ReBang,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id"
        entityColumn = "rebangId"
    )
    val contents: List<ContentBean>
)
```